# PhpStorm Xdebug remote ssh debugging of CLI script on Vagrant breakpoints not triggering

Tags: php, windows, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug a PHP script which is checked out locally on a Windows machine, then mapped to a Ubuntu VM (configured using Vagrant) which have Nginx, PHP and Xdebug installed. Also it's important to point out that I have php-fpm working in this setup and I have had a PHP script running as well, but in VSCode and not PhpStorm.

My PhpStorm config is:

[image]

My Xdebug config (currently, I have tried a million different config now):

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

I then configure my SSH tunnel like so:

```
putty.exe -ssh <vm-ip> -R 9003:localhost:9003
```

I am able to run the file and get its output in PhpStorm, but my breakpoints are not working. I just get the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And this is the content of the php file I am trying to debug:

[image]

So as we can see, the script executes without problem, the breakpoints just don't trigger. And as mentioned I have Xdebug working in PhpStorm for php-fpm when debugging websites, but when trying to debug a single PHP script I run into this problem.

I have tried so many different things, which makes me sure I am overlooking something basic I have forgotten. Right now I am suspecting PhpStorm for being annoying.. on output we can see the script is invoked with:

```
[vagrant://C:\vagrant]:/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9002 -dxdebug.client_host=192.168.1.185
```

I have not entered these `-d` arguments anywhere and I am not sure why PhpStorm keeps adding them (also it uses port 9002 and I have configured 9003). But I am not able to get anything working in VSCode as well, so I am properly doing something wrong.

My Xdebug config for php-fpm which is currently working in PhpStorm is:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.output_dir=/tmp/xdebug
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_log=/root/logs/xdebug.log

xdebug.force_display_errors=1
xdebug.force_error_reporting=1

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1

xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003

xdebug.remote_connect_back=0

xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
```

.. i then have a `PHP | Servers` settings for this as well:

[image]

If I try to use this config for PHP CLI script debugging, it's not working either (+ its PhpStorm waiting for Xdebug connections which I guess works a bit differently from PHP CLI script debugging)

What am I doing wrong since my breakpoints are not triggering when running single CLI scripts?

Comment: `xdebug.force_error_reporting=1` is likely not what you want, as it is a bitmask like `error_reporting`. Set it to `-1` instead to see all errors. There is also a lot of settings that only apply to Xdebug 2 here (all the `xdebug.remote_` ones for example).

Comment: `(also it uses port 9002 and i have configured 9003)`  — that is the real problem. You need to find out why it does this, as if the port is wrong, it won't connect to PhpStorm.

Comment: @Derick that is also what i am trying to figure out, but i cannot of the life of me understand why PhpStorm does this.. i have not configured it, and have never used port 9002 for remote ssh debugging. I supplied the screenshots of my CLI intepretors in hope that someone might know why this is happening.

Also, remember its the first xdebug.init config i am using for CLI debugging.. the last one is for php-fpm which works.. but its good to know i can remove all the `.remote_*` settings since i am using xdebug 3

Comment: found out why it uses 9002 instead of 9003.. which is because of `Settings | PHP | Debug` where the debug port is set to `9002.9003` i then removed the 9002 and not it uses 9003 as it should.. but it still uses the wrong `client_host` and i am not sure why

Comment: *"I have not entered these -d arguments anywhere and I am not sure why PhpStorm keeps adding them"* You can disable adding them by disabling the following option: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | PHP | Debug | Pass required configuration options through command line (still need to enable debug extension manually)` -- it's at the very bottom, under "Advanced settings" collapsible element.

Comment: You have Xdebug log enabled already -- what does it say? Do this: clear the log (so it's 2) an empty file; 0 bytes) and then try to debug. What will it contain now? Maybe it's the wrong IP?.. 3) Share the `xdebug_info()` output captured for the environment where it does not work (CLI) -- it will show your current/live settings. You may also compare them to the same but captured via a web page (where it works, as far as I understand).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it stupid but it works..

So essentially what annoyed me a lot, was that PHPSTORM added intepretor arguments which i did not specify, which i also mentioned above in the question.. it ended up executing the following on VM:

```
[vagrant://C:\vagrant]:/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9002 -dxdebug.client_host=192.168.1.185
```

I did not spoecify these `-d` arguments and could not for the life of me figure out how to make PHPSTORM remove them.. as mentioned in the question comments the port is specified through settings | php | debug | "debug port" so at least i could change that.. but the client_host was still wrong.

What i did to fix is, is just overriding it again so the cmd executed on the VM ended up being this (obs: i have used a lot of different ports to try and fix it.. which is why i am now using 9004):

```
[vagrant://C:\vagrant]:/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9004 -dxdebug.client_host=192.168.1.185 -dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 thefile-i-wanna-debug.php
```

My guess is this overrides the first, wrong, argument and then makes everything work.
You do this by adding intepretor arguments like so in your run-configuration:

[image]

and the xdebug config i ended up with, now matches all the guides i have found on SSH debugging as well, and is only:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9004
```

Success! :-D

[image]

Comment: i am still not sure how to remove PHPSTORMs default `-d` arguments, and if someone knows how to do this or change them, i will love them to the end of time!

Comment: *"i am still not sure how to remove PHPSTORMs default -d arguments, and if someone knows how to do this or change them, i will love them to the end of time!"* Just check my comments.